# Unable to see any web transactions of my Vertx application in glowroot

Tags: monitoring, vert.x

I am working on a vertx application running some apis.

After following instructions mentioned under https://github.com/glowroot/glowroot/wiki/Central-Collector-Installation, I was not able to see any Web transaction data  on glowroot central collector, here's what I tried.

I downloaded glowroot-central.jar, and after building the netty plugin from https://github.com/glowroot/glowroot/tree/master/agent/plugins/netty-plugin, placed it under plugins folder containing glowroot-central.jar file.

Next, started glowroot by calling "java -jar glowroot-central.jar"

And then passed in -javaagent:path/to/glowroot.jar to my JVM args of vertx application.

I was also able to confirm that my agent is able to connect to central collector from console output

Here's the output when I start my Vertx application, which confirms that agent is connecting to Central Collector

```
org.glowroot - Java version: 1.8.0_201 (Oracle Corporation / Mac OS X)
2019-04-05 12:31:43.988 INFO  org.glowroot - Java args: -javaagent:/Users/somefolder/glowroot/glowroot.jar
org.glowroot - agent id: "testserver"
org.glowroot - connected to the central collector http://0.0.0.0:8181, version 0.13.2, built 2019-03-27 17:05:44 +0000
```

I am also able to see my agent's name which is "testserver" on glowroot web UI. However I can not see any web transaction data. I called my API, few hundred times to using an automated tool and waited few min (~30 min), but I don't see anything :(